# How to get data for just two hour minute second from current day in sql

Tags: sql

Here I am trying to display hour, minute and second. i.e. current time is 10 am in the morning and I need data of 9 am. so here it display only hour not the actual time. Current time is 10.33 AM and I expect 9.33 AM data but the output shows only 9.00 AM data instead of current time.

```
set @EndHour = dateadd(hh,datediff(hh,0,GETDATE()),0)
set @StartHour = dateadd(hh,-1,@EndHour)
```

Current time is 10.33 AM and I expect 9.33 AM data but the data is displaying of 9.00 AM

Answer (score 0):

You definition of `@EndHour` is truncating the minutes and seconds.

If you want the value to the nearest minute, perhaps you want:

```
set @EndHour = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
set @StartHour = dateadd(hour, -1, @EndHour);
```

Or use `timefromparts()`:

```
select timefromparts(datepart(hour, getdate()) - 1,
                     datepart(minute, getdate()),
                     0, 0, 0
                    )
```